# Angular: Assign $scope value from ng-init to new variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

As per mentioned, Is it possible to assign `$scope` variable from `ng-init` to new variable?

see this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/21mGfltfkkHaOoLaGx3Q?p=preview)

If you see on my plunker, variable `$scope.adulttotTicket` have value of total ticket which is `13`. I create new variable using ng-init called `totTicket` and assign it to `$scope.adulttotTicket`

```
<p data-ng-init="totTicket = $scope.adulttotTicket"></p>
```

but when I output value `totTicket`, I got value `0`

```
totTicket: {{ totTicket }}
```

**#note** point of this question is, I want to assign new variable with value $scope variable

Anyone have any Idea would appreciate, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
<p data-ng-init="totTicket = adulttotTicket"></p>
```

Comment: no luck, got no value. see this plunker [https://plnkr.co/edit/21mGfltfkkHaOoLaGx3Q?p=preview]

Comment: @FaiZalDong check this https://plnkr.co/edit/k73hMYGuFYp8kag8va0V?p=preview

Comment: change to whatever value you want https://plnkr.co/edit/k73hMYGuFYp8kag8va0V?p=preview

Comment: please do not change any value. you just change value `adulttotTicket` to `10`.....

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135652/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-fai-zal-dong).

Comment: you just change this `$scope.adulttotTicket = 0">` to `adulttotTicket = 10">`. this variable `$scope.adulttotTicket` is important for me, do not change this value. What I need is, I want `totTicket` equal to this `$scope.adulttotTicket`. see this plunker [https://plnkr.co/edit/21mGfltfkkHaOoLaGx3Q?p=preview]

Comment: you should not use $scope in the template

Comment: If you see on `ng-repeat`, Im using this variable `$scope.adulttotTicket`, If you just simply change value `adulttoTicket` to `10`, you just ruined the value `+` inside `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

You got `0` value in `totTicket` because ng-init happens only once when the scope created when  `$scope.adulttotTicket` equals `0` ,while the "adulttotTicket" ng-init is happening every iteration of the ng-repeat.
Add some condition to `<p data-ng-init="totTicket = $scope.adulttotTicket">`

or change the assignment of the `totTicket` in the scope with `$watch` or something.

Comment: for now `$scope.adulttotTicket` have value `13`. Can we just simply create new variable and assign new variable to `$scope.adulttotTicket` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574048/does-ng-init-watch-over-change-on-instantiated-property-like-ng-model-does