# Custom directive inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this custom directive.
I call my directive like bellow, inside a `ng-repeat`.

> selectedMealCalc.calculated_foods as 'items', is an array of objects

```
 <!-- DIRECTIVE -->
    <div ng-repeat="option in [0,1,2,3,4]">
        <meal-option option="{{option}}"
                     items="selectedMealCalc.calculated_foods"
                     selectedmealcalc="selectedMealCalc"></meal-option> </div>
    <!-- DIRECTIVE -->
```

Then I created this directive in angularjs.

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('nutriApp').directive('mealOption', ['$compile', function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/checkins/meal-options.html',
        scope: {
          option: "@",
          items: "=",
          selectedmealcalc: "="
        },
        controller: ['$scope', 'Food', function($scope, Food) {
          $scope.sumFood = {};
          $scope.summerizeOption = function(foods) {
            if(foods.length > 0){
               $scope.sumFood = Food.summerize(foods);
            }
            return $scope.sumFood;
          };
        }]
      };
    }]);
```

And this HTML directive.

```
<div class="row" ng-init="filteredItems = ( items | filter: { food_option: option } )" ng-controller="CheckinsPlansCtrl">
  <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems.length > 0">
    Opção {{ option }}
    <table class="table table-calculo table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Alimento</th>
          <th>Quantidade</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="foodCalculation in filteredItems track by $index">
          <td>{{foodCalculation.food.name}}</td>
          <td>{{foodCalculation.gram_amount}} g</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I update the `selectedMealCalc.calculated_foods` the custom directive is not updating.
I have to close the modal and open again in my page to saw the new line.

Comment: yea. I think your problem is ng-init 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574048/does-ng-init-watch-over-change-on-instantiated-property-like-ng-model-does
try using a watch or move the ng-init logic to your controller

Comment: Hi @CharlieNg your answer is correct. Solved my problem. I did know this behavior of ng-init. Thank You.

Comment: nice!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this comment [Custom directive inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273701/custom-directive-inside-ng-repeat#comment81499556_47273701) in this post.
I removed the `ng-init` because ng-init:  "Only to initialize a property on the scope. I would recommend not to use it." as this another answer [Does ng-init watch over change on instantiated property like ng-model does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574048/does-ng-init-watch-over-change-on-instantiated-property-like-ng-model-does?answertab=active#tab-top)